# Reorder PHP array on random secondary value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-d array similar to as shown below. I need the array arranged by purchases (which is already done), and item types cannot be next to each other:

```
$productlist= array
(

    [1] => Array
        (
            [purchases] => 929
            [itemtype] => a
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [purchases] => 628
            [itemtype] => d
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [purchases] => 423
            [itemtype] => d
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [purchases] => 319
            [itemtype] => c
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [purchases] => 312
            [itemtype] => b
        )
}
```

So basically, I am trying to loop through this and try to shift an item up or down as long as the itemtype is different, and trying to keep the purchases the top priority.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) to order an array easily by random criteria.